# How to enable only specific href when all the href had been disabled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on disabled all the link in particular webpage where user status = 2. But because of the design. I used href to pass value instead of button. So, what I want now is want to enable the specific href.

This is my JavaScript :

```
$(function(){
    if(<{$status}> === 2){
        $("a").on("click", function(){
            var e = window.alert("Please fill in your details.");

            if(e == true)$("input[name=name]").focus();
            else $("input[name=name]").focus();
        return false;
        }); 
        //this is what I tried
        $("#save").off("click");
    }
})
```

This is HTML href that I want to enable:

```
<div class="button">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="xajax_editprofile(xajax.getFormValues('updateuser')); return false;" style="width:1px; visibility:hidden;">
<a href="#" id="save" onclick="xajax_editprofile(xajax.getFormValues('updateuser')); return false;">Save</a></div>
</div>
```

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: `if (this.id !== 'save') return false;`

Comment: is it need to declare 'this' at href?

Comment: By `href` did you mean anchor (`<a>`)? if so, Where is the portion of code that disables all anchors..?

Comment: if(<{$status}> === 2){
        $("a").on("click", function(){
            var e = window.alert("Please fill in your details.");

            if(e == true)$("input[name=name]").focus();
            else $("input[name=name]").focus();
        return false;
        });

Comment: @TJ : the first if condition will be disabled all the <a> anchor.

Comment: @user3517652 You are not disabling any anchor inside the if, or anywhere else in the code you've provided. If you are doing it in the else part or something, please update the proper code. And in the following `var e = window.alert("Please fill in your details.");` why are you using a variable, can't you simply do `alert("Please fill in your details.");` ?!!

Comment: @TJ : My code is completely done for disabling all the anchor when status = 2. This function will only work when I pass db status = 2 at my previous php page.

Comment: You have to understand that your code is **not disabling** anchor tags anywhere… -___- Hence your question is really unclear. That's why there are no answers. If you explain what you're doing properly, it's a simple thing to disable a specific anchor..